# Vagrant 1.8.3 + Docker Beta - container names to host hostfile

Tags: docker, vagrant

So I have been playing around with the new version of Vagrant that supports the docker beta (local docker on osx and windows).  Although I have hit a snag in relation to connecting to each of these containers via a hostname.

I am only running 2 containers: 1 for apache and another for postgres.  These are working fine and are linked correctly.
From the apache container (C1) I can connect to the postgres container (P1).
From the host machine i can connect to both using the exposed ports.

What I would really like to add now is the ability to connect to C1 using a hostname so that I can access the backend/frontend of the web app.

I have had a play around with vagrant-hostmanager and vagrant-hostsupdater but these dont appear to work with the docker provider.

I am guessing my only option is to fork one of the above projects and get working on the functionality I need, figured I would ask on here first.  If anyone knows a bit more and can point me in the right direction that would be great.

edit:  currently adding the hostname to the host as 127.0.0.1 with the name of the alias works, although the end goal is to automate this so that the step cannot be missed.

edit:  below is an example of the vagrant file that I am using for postgres

```rb
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.define "dev_postgres" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "db.dev.lan"
        db.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
        d.image = "postgres:9.4"
        d.ports = %w(5432:5432)
        d.remains_running = true
        d.force_host_vm = false
        d.create_args = %w(-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi, can you share your Vagrantfile for this? I have been trying to use vagrant 1.8.4 + windows docker beta, but when I vagrant up, vagrant is still trying to load boot2docker. This does not seem right, as docker is native. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @proxiblue my latest attempts at windows + docker RC had it up and running.  If i was you definitely check the install of docker, if you are not running the correct version of windows it will default back to the behaviour before docker supported and managed its own hyper-v vm.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I can run docker natively, and it works. Mayde vagrant cannot find it. Additionally on your question. Have a look at dnsdock. It is a docker based dns server.  I use it under linux succesfully. Once i get docker 4 windows going will get that sorted

Comment: @proxiblue thanks for the tip, i will have to have a look at dnsdock.  I did have some issues on windows with shares, the new RC may have taken care of that.  I found ensuring the firewall was on, restarting the network shares and making sure they were shared in the docker options gave about a 80% success rate.

the config line force_host_vm=false should tell vagrant to use the newer method (that doesnt require the vagrant host vm)

Comment: ahh - that must be what i am missing :  force_host_vm as it keeps trying to spin up a boot2dockr

Comment: Hi. Been a while. Not had much luck with docker in windows. Was hoping to improve a coworkers day by getting him off virtualbox. Latency is just crazy. Anyways. See this: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant-docker/blob/master/README.md you would be interested in the 'setup environment' section. Here i explain how to configure to allow usinf FQDN for the docker boxes.